# SpringBoot JUnit Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: spring-boot, junit

I have a simple REST app on SpringBoot.

```
@Service
public class XMPPAccountServiceImpl implements XMPPAccountService {

    private final XMPPAccountRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public XMPPAccountServiceImpl(XMPPAccountRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<XMPPAccount> getAll() {
        return repository.getAll();
    }

    @Override
    public XMPPAccount get(String server, String login) {
        return repository.get(server, login);
    }

    @Override
    public int remove(XMPPAccount account) {
        return repository.remove(account);
    }

    @Override
    public XMPPAccount edit(XMPPAccount account, String server, String login, String password) {
        return repository.edit(account,server,login,password);
    }


}
```

I want to test service level. But when I try to start test I get context error. I use only default properties, I don't have special context file.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class XmppTelegramApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private XMPPAccountService xmppAccountService;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        for (XMPPAccount s : xmppAccountService.getAll()) {
            System.out.println(s.toString());
        };
    }

}
```

What I need to do for start that test?

```
    2018-03-01 12:22:04.273  WARN 2624 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException
2018-03-01 12:22:04.281  INFO 2624 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-03-01 12:22:04.290 ERROR 2624 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed


java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:107)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:242)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

***
```

App is simple

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class XmppTelegramApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(XmppTelegramApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

How can I fix it? I don't have any problems when start app without test and use service

Add more exception info.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Bot</groupId>
    <artifactId>XMPP_Telegram</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>XMPP_Telegram</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

        <spring.version>5.0.4.RELEASE</spring.version>

        <!--MySQL-->
        <mysql.version>8.0.8-dmr</mysql.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.2.3</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>

        <!--    Tests  -->
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>XMPP-Telegram</finalName>
        <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencies>
        <!--Spring Boot-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!--Logging with SLF4J & LogBack-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--&lt;!&ndash;Spring&ndash;&gt;-->
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>-->
            <!--<exclusions>-->
                <!--<exclusion>-->
                    <!--<groupId>commons-logging</groupId>-->
                    <!--<artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>-->
                <!--</exclusion>-->
            <!--</exclusions>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->

        <!--DataBase-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Test-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

Comment: Please post the whole exception and the packages of the classes (Spring Boot app class and test class) as it may matter.

Comment: add more information. test class and main class and exception info

Comment: The error cause is really not clear. You have this warning before the exception: `Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: ....nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException` You could start by checking if you have the same warn outside test running.

Comment: no, I don't have any warm same that with start outside test. clean start, clean result (use @PostConstract in controller). But test doesn't start correct

Comment: Probably a classpath issue.  You pom could be useful.

Comment: add my pom to question

Comment: try changing `@SpringBootTest` to `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)`

Comment: doesn't help...